# Facing issue in deploying pods. its working fine if i only use affinity rule but after involving antiaffinity rules it is throwing error

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, devops, amazon-eks, affinity

```
error validating "helm/confluent-for-kubernetes/confluent-platform-6.1.0/iris-streaming-connect.yaml":  
error validating data:
ValidationError(Connect.spec.podTemplate.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution):  
invalid type for io.confluent.platform.v1beta1.Connect.spec.podTemplate.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:  
got "map", expected "array";  
if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: can you update your question with pod manifests file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.